# Reflection in mirror

Tags: optics, visible-light, reflection

My physics teacher said, that we need two light rays to reflect a point in space in a mirror. I doubt he's right. Do we need 1 or 2 light rays?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need two rays to construct the image. If you have one ray only, you can't determine the image distance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One light ray traces out a line through space. That's not enough information.

To know where on that line the light rays converge to from an image a second ray must be added.